# Pythonic way to populate a dictionary with count of values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

How can I write the following python snippet in a more pythonic way (using python2.7):

```
typeA = typeB = typeC = 0
    for count in counts:
        if count['storeType'] == 'dataStore':
            typeA = typeA + 1
        elif count['storeType'] == 'coverageStore':
            typeB = typeB + 1
        elif  count['storeType'] == 'remoteStore':
            typeC = typeC + 1

    count_dict = {
        'dataStore': dataStore,
        'coverageStore': coverageStore,
        'remoteStore': remoteStore
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

store_types = [count['storeType']  for count in counts]

print Counter(store_types)

# If you want dict, thought Counter is sub-class of dict. Convert to dict

dict(Counter(store_types))
```

Example of action :

```
In [1]: c = ['a','c','a','c']

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: Counter(c)
Out[4]: Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2})
```

Comment: This doesn't return a dictionary as the above.

Comment: A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects.

If you want to convert you can do ```dict(Counter(store_types))```

Comment: @user1919 updated with the ```dict``` conversion, though you can operate any operation on Counter that you want on dict.